# Multilable image classification optimization

Tags: image, optimization, multiclass-classification, conv-neural-network

I used convolutional network for multilable food image classification problem. The image contains 244*244*3 pixel. All the labels are one hot encoded(34 columns). I tried with SGD and adam optimization. But the accuracy does not exceed 30 percent. How can i improve the model?

Comment: It depends on task you are solving. Are classes unbalanced? Which loss function is used? Which is strategy for learning rate?